# App crashes when adding SceneKit constraints

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I tried to add the constraints for label and add it into the view.

View is added into the node getting crash.

```
func createNode() {
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 0.5, height: 0.8)) 
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hello"
    view.addSubview(label)

    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, 
                              constant: 18).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, 
                                 constant: 20).isActive = true
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constroint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    node.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = view
    node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0,-1)  
    scienview.scene.rootNode.addchildNode(node)
}
```

Anyone help me.
[image: Crashed logs]. Added inside of main thread also but not working.

Comment: "Added inside of main thread also but not working." Where? You need to call `createNode()` inside main thread.

Comment: Yes called inside of viewdidload() then no need to add main thread right but after crash I tried to add the main thread for testing inside of createNode() won't work.

Comment: Anyone have a solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This post (see answer) for basic game layout example: 58103566

As mentioned by Larme and you, set your alignment and constraints in viewDidLoad() of GameViewController: UIViewController

For most games, there is some kind of state that the game is in and I have a separate class for it.
GameNodes {}

- InitializeLevel - create nodes, etc.  If you start timers, make sure they are in the main thread.
- Start - game logic
- End - game logic
- Cleanup - remove nodes and graphics

I use delegates to communicate between VC's.  If the UI needs to be updated, then something like:
GameViewController

```
func showGameStatus(vText: String)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if(vText != "")
            {
                self.lblGameStatus.text = vText
                self.lblGameStatus.isHidden = false
                
            }
            else
            {
                self.lblGameStatus.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please update if any chance to add constraints or not because the problem is adding constraints..if add without constraints using frames working fine. Otherwise crash.